# vbscript regex to return string between hyphens with variations

Tags: regex, vbscript

Working with VBScript and Regex, and I will readily admit that I'm a rookie with regex, but do understand it's power and potential.

What I want to return *without* leading/trailing spaces:

```
how are you today
```

Here's an example of variations of input strings:

```
Me and you are here-how are you today
Me and you are here- how are you today
Me and you are here -how are you today
Me and you are here - how are you today
Me and you are here- how are you today-very well
Me and you are here- how are you today- very well
Me and you are here- how are you today -very well
Me and you are here- how are you today - very well
Me and you are here -how are you today-very well
Me and you are here -how are you today- very well
Me and you are here -how are you today -very well
Me and you are here -how are you today - very well
Me and you are here-how are you today-very well
Me and you are here-how are you today- very well
Me and you are here-how are you today -very well
Me and you are here-how are you today - very well
Me and you are here - how are you today-very well
Me and you are here - how are you today- very well
Me and you are here - how are you today -very well
Me and you are here - how are you today - very well
```

Edited to add additional variants of all the above with additional hyphens after the phrase 'very well'.  Example:

```
Me and you are here - how are you today -very well - good - and you -
Me and you are here - how are you today - very well - good
```

Here's the pattern I'm working with so far, however it's not quite there:

```
(?<=\-)(.*?)(?=\-|\z)
```

Comment: It is easy - use [`-\s*(.*?)(?:\s*-[^-]*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/nJKDtS/1) and grab `Submatches[0]`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew.  This did work, however now I've found even additional variants of input strings that may have additional hyphens after 'very well'.  Is there a way to accommodate for that as well....

Comment: Ok, so you need to only get the substring between the first and second `-`, right? Why not use `Split` and then trim the second item?

Comment: Correct....and I had actually started working on coding this using `Split`.

Comment: @CaveMud let's see your code then, we are not here to write it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The below worked for what I needed. Thanks for the help!

```
arrSubjectSplit = Split(objMessage.Subject,"-")
strCustomerName = Trim(arrSubjectSplit(1))
```